# control panel not working

Tags: windows-8, skype

I have a lot of apps installed on my Windows 8 PC like Skype, chrome, etc.

I want to uninstall those applications, but when I open uninstall a program from control  panel, all apps are not shown in there.

I mean if I want to uninstall Skype I am not being able to do it because its not shown on the list. I am really confused with that .

Any help would be appreciated.. cheers!!!

Comment: Perhaps it's a "Style" (or "Metro") app. If so, locate the app on Win8 start screen, right click on it and then select "uninstall".

Comment: You mean that the installed programs are not appearing in Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features. Try to reinstall one of the missing programs without uninstalling it and tell us if it reappears in the Control Panel.you also run sfc in the elevated mode. Read at http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstall softwares:

- [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner)
- [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/)
- [IOBit Uninstaller](http://www.iobit.com/advanceduninstaller.html)

The other way is to uninstall manually. Open registry, go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, look for the software you want to uninstall, copy the value from the UninstallString key and run it in a command prompt